# Did I accidentally brick my GPU and how do I downgrade my BIOS ver?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, graphics-card, bios

I think I may have made a mess of the actual problem and now have to deal with multiple ones! A long post since I have to type out all the things that I have done, thanks for your time !!!

Firstly, I had a hard disk failure and had to replace it with another one(obviously all the works that come with it, now running **Win 10 pro build:19042.867 version: 20H2**).

Completely unrelated to this, somehow, the cooling fan in the graphics card (**Zotac 1050 Ti** )was broken and I had to fix it using a super glue. When I put it back on, they ran as usual, but the screen had red dotted lines and was running on windows basic display adapter driver, since there was no drivers installed, I thought may be that'll fix it, but when i installed the driver from CD that came with it, the Nvidia control panel wouldn't open stating the versions were incompatible, then when I tried to install the latest version, the system was stuck on loading screen with blocks of red pixels,     [pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qeprq.jpg)

This was a quite a common thing, that was fixed by driver update, but since that didn't work out, I read that updating the bios and / or clearing the CMOS might help, so I went with the wasy solution that was updating the BIOS my Motherboard (**STRIX H270F**) had a updated BIOS (*1205 , 2018 release*) than what was already there(*it was in 800 series not sure of the no. , 2017 release*)

Now, the computer is stuck in booting screen when i try to use the graphics card. At this point after changing so many variables, I don't know where I have messed up. I tried to downgrade the BIOS version to one of the available 800 series in the official website, but it says the "selected file is not a proper BIOS file " (the naming convention is exactly the same as in the file that i used for upgrading; the thumb drive is formatted to exFat)

Here are some of the pictures from the graphics setting in the BIOS:

After the BIOS update without graphics card in the system [pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jLg5.jpg)
After the BIOS update with graphics card in the system [pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CMaVv.jpg)

In the BIOS the correct PCIE slot is highlighted and says running at x16 Native (Before BIOS update, it showed running at x4 Native ) [I tried uploading the pic, but could not ]

The fact that the Mobo still recognizes the card is keeping my hopes alive that I didn't do anything stupid! Hopefully it is a silly mistake somewhere!

I was reading up on flashing the GPU to the stock firmware and stuff, could that work!?

Thanks and regards
Somasundharam S

Comment: I bet you fried your GPU.  Do you have another card you can test it with?  I also fried a high end NVidia card when the fan quit functioning.  If you can, swap it out before proceeding (even temporarily) to make sure it isn't part of the mess you are dealing with.. this is my opinion.  Also.. super glue to fix a component on a GFX card.. "my compliments to the chef".. you do whatever you have to.

Comment: I'm able to use my computer with graphics from CPU , i dont have another card , actually i'm confused . . . How will another card help with the diagnosis ? abt the super glue: a blade in the fan was broken and I just glued it together! I tried to run it w/o that but it was wobbly and I feared that the PCIE slot may get damaged in the long run! after that fix, the fans were running at normal speeds though . . . :(

Comment: "a blade in the fan was broken and I just glued it together! " .. SO COOL :) .. You can even fry an onboard GPU.. I would still try another external card (yes, it can make a difference).. if you can find one.  Sorry about your loss.. :^P   --- :(

Comment: well, I'm taking it to a service center later this morning. Since i don't have any other system to test the card on or an extra card to check where the problem is, I don't have much of an option now :/

Comment: I was talking to a technical guy from Zotac via mail , he says it could be a GPU or Memory IC pblm, subject to testing the HW on another PC. So I'll post how it turns out later today

Comment: Good luck sir.. I can't say your name.. but I can wish you luck. ;)

Comment: thanks... I guess! Perhaps I should have come to the forums when I was still able to log into the system. anyways, I was thinking maybe downgrading the BIOS might help, since, the problem started after updating, but I am not able to do that as well... any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry for your loss...I melted a GPU with cat hair once. Long-haired cat's sheddings got sucked into the intake of the fan and jammed it. I didn't notice until the card died. Good Luck!