# how to flash a gpu to the stock bios?

Tags: windows-10, bios, nvidia-graphics-card, flash, freedos

I have some noob qs about flashing my Zotac 1050 ti 4 GB model:

For some back story: [Did I accidentally brick my GPU and how do I downgrade my BIOS ver?](https://superuser.com/questions/1633366/did-i-accidentally-brick-my-gpu-and-how-do-i-downgrade-my-bios-ver)

Following on: I did take it to the service center, they said that the graphics card didn't work with other mother boards too and that my mother board worked fine with a different graphic card.

Now I would like to try everything before throwing it away for good! On that matter, I was looking at some tutorials for flashing from YouTube and I have some questions on that. Here are the tutorials that I saw: [Flashing a Laptop GPU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OvpZqas0H0c) (Nvidia Card) ,
[Flashing a Desktop GPU](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mTqNP-N38BY) (AMD Card). Both have very similar instructions, but I am unclear about the following things:

1. How should the connection to monitor be? (shd I have the graphics card ON and take the o/p from the MOBO(firstly is it possible though?! i mean can we have the default graphics as CPU and still have GPU in the system) or just take o/p from the GPU)
2. Since Computer won't boot; I have to use the DOS method to flash, but unfortunately there's no DOS version of Nvflash available, how do I go about this? I read something [here](https://www.techpowerup.com/forums/threads/nvflash-dos-version.231829/) about freeDOS. how do I use it in tandem with the Nvflash that is available for Windows.

Thanks for your time!
Regards!

Comment: In order to flash the stock bios onto a GPU, you must first extract the stock bios off the card.  If the card is not functional, that is difficult to do, for what should be obvious reasons.

Comment: I thought we will be using bios from the techpowerup website !?

Comment: but the video says we can get a working bios for our model from here: https://www.techpowerup.com/vgabios/

Comment: Let me say this another way.  The GPU has to be detectable. If that is the case then you could try flashing the card from within Windows, if Windows cannot boot with the card installed, it very unlikely freeDOS would boot with it installed.  Your going to need a working display, in order to flash the bios, during the flashing process you will probably lose your display if your using IT as your display adapter.

Comment: The graphics card is detected in the BIOS, i mean the correct slot is highlighted in the tools / graphics card info / GPU post section of my BIOS ; GOP/BBIOS status is shown as "Select a valid GPU" .

Comment: It being detectable in BIOS is far removed from being able to flash it's firmware within (Windows or FreeDOS).  I hope you have a second GPU to accomplish what you want.

Comment: Understood, just for the sake of trying, can you walk me through how to get the nvflash working with the freeDOS; i get what you're saying, i'm just desperate to make it work! also, will it be possible to boot with CPU graphics while still having the GPU in the MOBO(my 1st Q) if i'm not able to see a screen with GPU as the primary graphics

Comment: You have not given me enough information to determine if your CPU even has an iGPU.  I can guarantee you, if the GPU is not outputting anything, FreeDOS won't detect it.

Comment: I have a I5 7600 CPU, It has Intel HD graphics 630.