# can a dead gpu still work with Microsoft Basic display adapter

Tags: windows-10, drivers, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, display-driver

For some back story -> [Did I accidentally brick my GPU and how do I downgrade my BIOS ver?](https://superuser.com/q/1633366) If you're still not able to follow, don't worry; even I don't know how I  ended up with a "dead" GPU when I went to the service center for changing my (definitely) dead hard disk..!

so after all the hassle, I thought the gpu is dead until today when i had some time and decided to check if it will work... I plugged in the gpu and the computer booted with gpu as input to the monitor **with basic microsoft display driver**

when I upgraded the drivers it got updated to

> date **30 9 2020**
> driver version **27.21.14.5671**

then I got the below screen... [desktop with checkered black squares](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLEqS.jpg) but was able to move around, so i thought maybe downloading more recent update would stabilise things.. as it was downloading, i clicked on start to get to device manager but the computer got stuck, so had to restart(with monitor still plugged to gpu) and i got a black screen with red blocks of pixel after the boot logo...

I read somewhere that the blocks of pixels can be because of RAM (in GPU)overheating (eventual damage to to RAM) and not necessarily because of a problem in the GPU itself... If so how can it work with basic display driver...

Then with input to monitor from cpu, i was able to log in to the computer(gpu still plugged into the mobo)... the device manager shows that the drivers are up to date and here are some info from

device manager > properties for gpu > details

inf section - section046

service - nvlddmkm

device stack - {\Driver\nvlddmkm , \Driver\ACPI , \Driver\pci }

has Problem , is reboot required , pending software install - false

is connected , is present - true

Could it be that the last update was a bit abrupt and that caused some unstability or the gpu is done for good? (if any other parameter needs to be checked, let me know in the comments so i can add them too)

oh.. also when i tried opening the nvidia geforce experience the computer hung again.. so had to restart ; also while typing this out, i got a [blue screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wn5pG.jpg) (chrome had so many tabs open..could it be the cause?!)so had to restart again...

If you guys can take a look at this issue it'll be great, until then I'm going to set the driver for GPU as basic Microsoft driver and try to install the driver from the CD that came with this... the driver date is around 2017.. so maybe I have to work my way up... I'll update any progress here...

another q: does flashing the gpu help here... ?!

**UPDATE:** after confirming that the GPU is indeed dead, I am using output from the mobo for monitor input.. I was using one chrome window with multiple tabs open and spotify playing music via the speakers in the monitor(i don't have separate speakers), suddenly I got a BSOD with message "Page fault in non paged area". After a while I was using only chrome window and got another BSOD with message "kmode exception not handled". Later while I was waking the computer from sleep, I got a BSOD with 1st message again.. !

Should I be worried..? Earlier today when the BSOD appeared first, I read that it could be because of driver issues.. and knowing that I was constantly changing display drivers yesterday, I headed over to windows update center and installed all the [updates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVohS.png) <- click

under the drivers in the update history ..

NVIDIA - Display - 27.21.14.5671

Intel Corporation - Display - 26.20.100.7528

INTEL - System - 7/18/1968 12:00:00 AM - 10.1.11.4

ASMedia Technology Inc - USB Controller - ASMedia USB3.1 eXtensible Host Controller

Intel Corporation - Extension - 8/27/2018 12:00:00 AM - 24.20.100.6291

these are the files that were installed today...

Is it my doing ? if so how do I stabilize this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter needs is a framebuffer.  Basically the graphics chip can take in an image constructed by the operating system and display it on a monitor.

All this requires is the most basic graphics features, it doesn't require the graphics card to ramp up to any high power mode or any kind of 3D operation, it just needs an input, and the raster output of the graphics card to work.

If the compute (CUDA/Shader) units of the graphics card were damaged by it overheating then you could have a major section of the GPU pipeline that is broken for "normal" Windows, as it uses the GPU for desktop compositing, but can be bypassed with the Basic Adapter.

If the graphics card works for viewing the BIOS, then it will work with the Basic Adapter.

Knowing what actually went wrong is difficult to establish. It could be that one or more memory chips have failed and the card is unable to fully establish how much or what type of memory it has, the black checkerboard makes me think that one of your banks of memory on the graphics card has failed. Either the memory controller in the chip for that side has dies, or a memory chip itself is dead and has taken out the rest of the bank.

I've seen a few graphics cards that have failed and only worked in the most basic mode and refused to install "proper" drivers to use the full card functionality.

Comment: i'm getting BSOD with the following messages "page fault in nonpaged area" and "Kmode exception not handled" alternatively after few minutes of usage, i'm having only one chrome window... any idea why this might be happening?